# Assigning Delegate for Modally presented Form Sheet in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have an iPad view that presents a modal form sheet that is essentially a 'settings' view. 
From there the user can go to a specific setting. I need to be able to refresh the main iPad view when the modal view is dismissed.

Therefore, I need a delegate protocol to call `-(void)refreshTable` when the modal view is dismissed. This wouldn't be a problem except when I present the modal view, the delegate I need to assign, is a view that is 'pushed' from the presented view. (Screenshot)

[image]

Here is how I'm presenting the modal form sheet:
I'm encapsulating it in a UINavigationController because it needs to push other views.
(I would just assign the delegate here, but the view with the protocol gets pushed from AddView) `NewAftpViewController` is the view controller which has the protocol.

```
-(void)presentAddView:(id)sender {

    AddView *avc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"add"];
    UINavigationController *navcont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:avc];
    navcont.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navcont animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And here is my protocol in the pushed view:

```
@protocol RefreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate
-(void)refreshTable;
@end

@interface NewAftpViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <RefreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate> refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two ways to do this. You should be able to get a reference to that left most controller in your post with `[self.navigationController presentingViewController]` -- you'll need to cast `self.navigationController` to whatever class that is. Then in your  `NewAftpViewController`, you can set the delegate like this:

```
self.delegate = [(cast here)self.navigationController presentingViewController];
```

But this seems to defeat the purpose of using a delegate -- the delegator is not supposed to know what class the delegate is, but here you have to set it explicitly. Instead of using a delegate, you could just call a method on that controller directly.

I think the better way, in situations like this, is to use an `NSNotification`. That seems cleaner and simpler to me. Just post a notification from `NewAftpViewController`, and have your first controller listen for it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `prepareForSeague` method, where you push the next View Controller, you can set the delegate:

```
CustomController *controllerToPush = segue.destinationViewController;
controllerToPush.delegate = self.navigationController.parentViewController;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, maybe I'm missing something about delegation completely because I get the same error whatever I try. everyone's code examples use: self.delegate when the id for my delegate is 'refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate' so shouldn't it be self.refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate or controllerToPush.refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate? Neither is working for me at the moment.(for any answer)

Comment: When I try your code, wether I'm using .delegate or .refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate, I get the following warning: ...AddView.m:44:46: Assigning to 'id<RefreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate>' from incompatible type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: You may have to make a cast there to remove the warning: `CustomController *controllerToPush = (CustomController *)segue.destinationViewController;`. But first, you should check in the StoryBoard the class of the pushed View Controller to be set correctly. About delegation, you should call `[self.delegate refreshAfterAddingNewAftpDelegate]` in the last view controller (the one that was pushed), maybe from the `viewWillDisappear` method.